# Error al conectarse a Mysql usando Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Estoy tratando de conectarme a Mysql desde la consola de comandos con los comandos mysql y luego mysql -u root -p

```
C:\Users>mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 11
Server version: 10.4.22-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

sin embargo me sale la conexion es a MariaDB cosa que no quiero

Comment: debes validar en el path si tienes a mariadb agregada! si estas en windows puedes usar el comando `where mysql` y ver que path tienes registrados!

Comment: el path esta correcto de hecho es este C:\xampp\mysql\bin por eso no entiendo porque me sale Maria porque de hecho revisando la carpeta de xampp ni aparece Maria @Bryro

Comment: en xamp viene por defecto es maria db que es la version community... lo dice en su pagina principal en grande! https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html

Comment: pero sale tambien la carpeta de mysql, asi que no entiendo @Bryro

Comment: Descarga MySQL Comunity Server desde [su página](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql), instálalo; si es para dev, le puedes poner inicio manual. Luego, desde el Xampp solo arrancas el servicio de Apache y ya.

Comment: gracias ahorita lo hago @aeportugal

Comment: @anonymuus_gp mariadb es mysql para que se comprenda mejor te dejo el link de wikipedia [mariadb](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB)... y como te comenta aerpotugal   si tas aprendiendo no veras diferencia alguna.

Comment: okay muchas gracias ya reviso, de todas formas coloque lo que me pusiste de where mysql, puse la ruta correcta pero ahora me sale C:\Users> mysql -u root -p
"mysql" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. independientemente si estoy en la carpeta users o en la disco c @Bryro